# Send instant SMS when user clicks a CTA in an email using journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sms

I need to build a welcome journey that sends a welcome email when the contact enters the journey and then if the user clicks one of the CTA in the email, we need to trigger an instant SMS message.

I was wondering if that is something that could be done in journey builder and could you advise me how could I achieve that?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a cloud page (Smart Capture form) and use this cloud page in journey to send SMS. Journy will have "Entry Source" as this cloud page.Also, journey will have SMS activity in it.

In you email, when CTA happens, you can redirect user to this cloud page and this page will send SMS using Journey.